# What is wrong with the recognition of this HID device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kali-linux, drivers, hid

I have a Panasonic CF-31RECAXDR Toughbook with `6.3.0-kali1-amd64`.
*(https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=2c021f93de)*

Kali does not recognize the HID device *Fujitsu Component Limited USB Touch Panel*, no response nor shows it in settings.(*https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0430-0532*)

Here is the `dmesg` output:

```
[    3.816330] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0430, idProduct=0532, bcdDevice=20.02
[    3.816347] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.816357] usb 2-1.6: Product: USB Touch Panel
[    3.816366] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Fujitsu Component
[    3.836349] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    3.898049] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    4.077503] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[    4.096918] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    4.116601] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    4.116608] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.119781] input: Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/0003:0430:0532.0001/input/input13
[    4.119940] hid-generic 0003:0430:0532.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
```

Here the `lsusb` description:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0430:0532 Fujitsu Component Limited USB Touch Panel
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0430 Fujitsu Component Limited
  idProduct          0x0532 
  bcdDevice           20.02
  iManufacturer           1 Fujitsu Component
  iProduct                2 USB Touch Panel
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0022
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               36mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      68
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Here is the `udevadm info`:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6
M: 2-1.6
R: 6
U: usb
T: usb_device
D: c 189:130
N: bus/usb/002/003
L: 0
V: usb
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/002/003
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: PRODUCT=430/532/2002
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: BUSNUM=002
E: DEVNUM=003
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=130
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3815419
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=USB_Touch_Panel
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Touch\x20Panel
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0532
E: ID_SERIAL=Fujitsu_Component_USB_Touch_Panel
E: ID_VENDOR=Fujitsu_Component
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Fujitsu\x20Component
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0430
E: ID_REVISION=2002
E: ID_USB_MODEL=USB_Touch_Panel
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Touch\x20Panel
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ID=0532
E: ID_USB_SERIAL=Fujitsu_Component_USB_Touch_Panel
E: ID_USB_VENDOR=Fujitsu_Component
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ENC=Fujitsu\x20Component
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ID=0430
E: ID_USB_REVISION=2002
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Fujitsu Component Limited
E: ID_PATH_WITH_USB_REVISION=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usbv2-0:1.6
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.6
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_6
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_1d_0-usb-0_1_6
E: TAGS=:seat:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:
```

It uses `hid-generic` module:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/6.3.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-generic.ko
license:        GPL
description:    HID generic driver
author:         Henrik Rydberg
alias:          hid:b*g*v*p*
depends:        hid
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           hid_generic
vermagic:       6.3.0-kali1-amd64 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
```

The device modalias are:

```
pci:v00008086d00001C26sv000010F7sd00008338bc0Csc03i20

usb:v0430p0532d2002dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in00

hid:b0003g0001v00000430p00000532
```

The last one is in: `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/0003:0430:0532.0002`

Finally `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Panasonic Laptop Support                  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

There is not a hotkey to enable/disable the touch panel.

Any advice of what is missing?

Comment: this can help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchscreen